# Python unexpected indent

Tags: python, syntax-error

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "python", line 2
if Number == "50" and "51" and "52" and "53" and "54" and "55" and "56 "and "57" and "58" and "59" and "60":
 ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Code:

```
Number = input ("Please enter a number between 50 and 60: ")
    if Number == "50" and "51" and "52" and "53" and "54" and "55" and "56 "and "57" and "58" and "59" and "60":
print ("The number ") + (Number) + (" is with in range")
```

I'm trying to run this python code but i keep getting error message "unexpected indent". I'm not sure whats wrong. The spacing seem to be fine. Any idea's?

Comment: Your `if` statement is also wrong (Not the cause of the Error). It should be `if Number == "50" and Number == "51" ....`and so on. Check this for reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-one-variable-against-multiple-values

Comment: Use the: if Number in ("50", "51", ...):

Comment: In addition to the syntax error pointed out by Bhargav, a number can't be 50 *and* 51.

Comment: You are almost certainly mixing tabs and spaces. Don't do that, configure your editor to expand tabs to 4 spaces, and ask it to convert any existing tabs to spaces. Other than that, see [How do I test one variable against multiple values?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15112125) to avoid the other mistake in your code.

Comment: The lizard is right. You most likely want `or` not `and`

Comment: @MartijnPieters It's not tabs/spaces..

Comment: @Izkata: not after that final edit from the OP, no.

Comment: *"The spacing seem [sic] to be fine"* - nope...

Answer (score 3):

Your indentation is backwards. The line *after* the `if` should be indented.

```
Number = input ("Please enter a number between 50 and 60: ")
if Number == "50" and "51" and "52" and "53" and "54" and "55" and "56 "and "57" and "58" and "59" and "60":
    print ("The number ") + (Number) + (" is with in range")
```

Comment: I can't in good conscience upvote this knowing you didn't address the faults in the condition itself.

Comment: For the record, I 100% endorse Bhargav's comment linking to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-one-variable-against-multiple-values :-)

Comment: i'm new to python i don't know how to code but i'm trying my best to learn it thank for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Have you indented the line after `if` with four spaces ? Please note there is a logic flaw in your code; your `if` statement will never be true. Did you mean to use `or`  instead? In that case you can implement it more efficient using this code snippet:

```
Number = input ("Please enter a number between 50 and 60: ")
if 50 <= Number <= 60:
    print ("The number ") + (Number) + (" is with in range")
```

Comment: You need to convert the return value of `input()` to an integer, in Python 3. Not that that `print()` line would work in Python 3...

Answer (score 0):

You have your `if` statement indented and your `print` not indented.  It should
be the other way around.  Also, as previous folks have noted, your `if` statement
is incorrect, which will generate another error.:

```
Number = input("Please enter a number between 50 and 60: ")
if Number in ['50', '51', '52', '53', '54', '55', '56', '57', '58', '59', '60']:
    print("The number %s is within range" % Number)
```

I'm not sure why you're treating the number as a string, though.  I'd do it as:

```
try:
    Number = int(input("Please enter a number between 50 and 60: "))
except ValueError:
    print("You were supposed to enter a number!")
else:
    if 50 <= Number <= 60:
        print("The number %d is within range" % Number)
```

Comment: `if 50 <= int(Number) <= 60:`... (and handle the potential `ValueError` exception).

Comment: @Martijn - Thanks.  I just thought of that myself.